# Dart: Callback method not executed

Tags: dart, callback

While getting familiar with Dart and callback methods, I tried to run the following code in dartpad. However, the function fIn() is not executed. Can anyone please tell me why?

```
void main() {
int counter = 1;
  
  void secondMethodCallback() {
    print(counter);
    counter++;
    print(counter);
  }
  
  // As a Lambda-Expression its not working; only as "secondMethodCallback"
  firstMethod(counter, () => secondMethodCallback);

}

void firstMethod(int intIn, Function() fIn){
  print("in firstMethod");
  fIn();
}
```

When I pass over "secondMethodCallback" without the Lambda-Expression like this, it works:

```
  firstMethod(counter, secondMethodCallback);
```

2nd Question: It doesn't seem to make a difference, if I write in firstMethod "Function" or "Function()". Can anyone explain this please?

3rd Question: Is it somehow possible, to manipulate "counter" inside firstMethod?

4rd Question: Is it somehow possible, to manipulate "intIn" inside fIn when it is executed inside firstMethod?

Best regards and big thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  // As a Lambda-Expression its not working; only as "secondMethodCallback"
  firstMethod(counter, () => secondMethodCallback);
```

you have a lambda expression that returns a function object. you missed the `()` to call it:

```
  // As a Lambda-Expression its not working; only as "secondMethodCallback"
  firstMethod(counter, () => secondMethodCallback());
```

regarding the other questions: familiarize yourself with value types vs pointer/reference types, or rather with the difference between pass by value and pass by reference.
and then learn about closures in dart.

Comment: Uff, true, thank you. Could you also take a look at my other questions?